# Генерация <option> для datalist ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

привет! есть код

```
<input type="text" list="list"/>
    <datalist id="list">
        <script>
            @foreach (var c in ViewBag.List)
            {
               @:$('<option class="oplist"></option>', { text: "@c.Name" }).appendTo($('#list'));
            }
        </script>
    </datalist>
```

Он как бы в теории генерит список для datalist но что-то не генерит(((
если убрать символ @ у `@с.Name` но генерит строку c.Name по количеству елементов но с @ не чего не происходит!!
Помогите я ваще ппц не пойму почему

Comment: На сколько я помню, `ViewBag` необходимо приводить к конкретному типу, который Вы будете использовать. Получается вам надо в объявлении цикла привести `ViewBag.List` к нужному типу коллекций. 
Например: `@foreach (var c in (List<User>)ViewBag.List)`. А также все это возможно написать без применения JavaScript, как было написано в ответе @Igor.

Comment: @V.Birkos Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я помню, `ViewBag` необходимо приводить к конкретному типу, который Вы будете использовать, так как он является `dynamic`. Получается, Вам надо в объявлении цикла привести ViewBag.List к нужному типу коллекций. Например:

```
@foreach (var c in (List<User>)ViewBag.List).
```

А также все это возможно написать без применения JavaScript, как было написано в ответе @Igor.

Answer (score 0):

Тут можно вообще обойтись без javascript-a.

```
<input type="text" list="list"/>
<datalist id="list">
  @foreach (var c in ViewBag.List)
  {
    <option class="oplist">@c.Name</option>
  }
</datalist>
```

Comment: не чего не поменяло на строке `$('<option class="oplist"></option>').text("@c.Name" ).appendTo($('#list'));` ошибка компиляции без знака `@:`